# Responsive background with a long height image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a really long image, 2263 x 8192 pixels. I would like to create a website with a background (of that image) that covers the width of the window, but also with the full height of the image, without losing responsiveness.

The idea is to have this long scrolling image, divided in different/sections parts with a fix height. Exactly as a landing page with different sections, but instead of having different backgrounds for each section, I want a long image.

Any ideas?

Comment: pls show us what you have tried so far. this question is to vague. or show us what you are looking for with a picture

Comment: let me make a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adrianvcch/mettmnrt/2/ @FutureCake

Comment: so what is exactly the problem with this jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/WfkIpCq.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    color: #fff;
}
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f1zu318n/

Comment: But I do not want a fix image, it must scroll down all the image

Comment: @AdriánVázquez I change my answer

Comment: Hi, thats good but when I reduce the window, there is a huge white space on the bottom of the page @Mikhail

Comment: @AdriánVázquez hm. But I not see this issue. I record video https://youtu.be/7dbtlkv4qsU

Comment: Thats great! Then I wil check the problem in my pc.

Answer (score 1):

```
margin-top:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
width:100%;
```